# XGBoostError: sklearn needs to be installed in order to use this module ( GCP Datalab)

Tags: python, xgboost, google-cloud-datalab

I am trying to use Xgboost in GCP datalab. I have already installed sklearn but I keep getting the error :

> " XGBoostError: sklearn needs to be installed in order to use this
>   module"

Below is the code I used:

```
import sklearn
!pip3 install xgboost
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier
model = XGBClassifier()
```

I have tried using Python v 2.7 instead, but no luck...does anyone know how to solve this issue in GCP Datalab?

Comment: Please note that If I try the same in Jupyter notebook, there is no issue, but GCP Datalab throws this error...

Comment: Your code worked fine for me. Have you changed anything about the Datalab environment? Installed/uninstalled any packages?

Comment: Nope no change...I couldn't find a way to make it work, so now I am using Jupyer notebook in GCP instead.

Answer (score 5):

I also faced the same issue, on python 3.7 32bit on ipython.

Solution: Uninstall the **xgboost** package by `pip uninstall xgboost` on terminal/cmd. Cross-check on the your console if you cannot import it. Now again install **xgboost** `pip install xgboost` or `pip install xgboost-0.81-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl`, given that you have already installed **sklearn**, it will work on newer console session.

xgboost wheel Link: https://pypi.org/project/xgboost/#files

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error with a more complicated project, after releasing a new version suddenly it failed.

luckily in my case, I had docker images for each version, and was able to use `pip freeze` to see what changed.

In both version I used `xgboost==0.81`
In the version that worked I had `scikit-learn==0.21.3` and in the new version it was `scikit-learn==0.22`

surprisingly enough, that's now what caused the issue. I've tried to uninstall `xgboost` like it was suggested here and reverted `scikit-learn` to the version is was originally on, and still no luck.

what did cause the issue was an update of `numpy` from `1.17.4` to `1.18.0`. 
reverting it solved it for me (not sure why)

this was python 3.6 on ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

For me un- then re-installing first sklearn and then xgboost did the trick